# ffmpeg concatenated audio not present in the output

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two audio files and add it to a video file but the output does not contain the audio.

I can see the duration of the output video is the sum of the two audio. But the audio is not present.

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i a1.mp3 -i a2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1][2]concat=a=1:n=2:v=0[s0]" -map 0 -map '[s0]' -shortest 'out.mp4'
```

Any help on this issue would be great!

Comment: The part where you set the audio codec is missing?

Comment: Change `-map 0` to `-map 0:v`

Comment: Thanks @Gyan that helped! Can you please post that as an answer? I'll mark that as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-map 0` is leading to the audio stream in the first input being included and written before the filtered audio, so many players will just play that one.

Change `-map 0` to `-map 0:v`, so only the original video is mapped.